# NoSuchFileException when creating a file using nio

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I am trying to create a new file using java nio, and I'm running into a createFile error. Error looks like this:

```
 createFile error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jchang/result_apache_log_parser_2015/06/09_10:53:49
```

code segment looks like this:

```
 String filename = "/Users/jchang/result_apache_log_parser_" + filename_date;
        Path file = Paths.get(filename);
        try {
            Files.createFile(file);
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
            System.err.format("file named %s" +
                    " already exists%n", file);
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x);
        }
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Files.create(...)` does only create the file, not the folder. Could this be your porblem or does the folder exist?

Comment: Oh jeez do I need the file type at the end? e.g. .txt?

Comment: No, you don't. But the path to the file (i.e. the folder, in which the file resides) must be present.

Comment: OK it definitely exists then, it's just my home directory that I'm linking to.

Comment: Okay... can you please make the exact line, where the exception occurs?

Comment: `Files.createFile(file)` causes an IOException which is caught and prints out the NoSuchFileException.

Comment: `Files.createDirectories(file.getParent());` - Are you sure Users is written with a capital U?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was the slashes in the variable I was using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that Turing85 was correct.  Your `filename_date` variable has slashes in it.  So `/Users/jchang/result_apache_log_parser_2015` has to exist as a directory.  That is the cause of the `NoSuchFileException`, missing directory.

Comment: But there is another problem (at least under windows): the colons are illegal characters. I am working on a solution

Comment: Exactly, I would also recommend to replace some characters in the `filename_date` into valid characters. For example, `filename_data = filename_date.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_");`

Answer (score 6):

Your code has at least two problems. First: you have path delimiters in your filename (`/`). Second: at least under Windows, your solution has illegal characters within the filname (`:`).

To get rid of the first problem, you can go down two routes: a) create all the folders you need or b) change the delimiters to something different. I will explain both.

To create all folders to a path, you can simply call

```
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
```

where `path` is a file (important!). By calling `getParent()` on file, we get the folder, in which `path` resides. `Files.createDirectories(...)` takes care of the rest.

b) Change the delimiters: Nothing easier than this:

```
String filename =  "/Users/jchang/result_apache_log_parser_"
                 + filename_date.replace("/", "_")
                                .replace(":", "_");
```

This should yield something like `/User/jchang/result_apache_parser_2015_06_09_10_53_29`

With b) we have taken care of the second problem as well.

Now lets set it all together and apply some minor tricks of `nio`:

```
String filename =  "/Users/jchang/result_apache_log_parser_"
                 + filename_date.replace('/', '_')
                                .replace(':', '_');

Path file = Paths.get(filename);
try {
    // Create sub-directories, if needed.
    Files.createDirectories(file.getParent());
    // Create the file content.
    byte[] fileContent = ...;
    // We do not need to create the file manually, let NIO handle it.
    Files.write(file
                , fileContent
                // Request permission to write the file
                , StandardOpenOption.WRITE
                // If the file exists, append new content
                , StandardOpenOption.APPEND
                // If the file does not exist, create it
                , StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For more information about `nio` click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Answer (score 5):

As many said, you need to create intermediate directories, like ../06/..

So use this, before creating the file to create dirs which don't exist,

```
Files.createDirectories(mPath.getParent());
```

So your code should be:

```
    Path file = Paths.get(filename);
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(file.getParent());
        Files.createFile(file);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
        System.err.format("file named %s" +
                " already exists%n", file);
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x);
    }
```

Comment: Working for me.